# How to I assign the value of one item in a tuple to another in Python?

Tags: python, tuples, bubble-sort

I need to sort items in a tuple using the bubble sort method for a project in my computer science class. The items are all integers.

```
   SwapAgain = True
    
    while SwapAgain == True:
        SwapAgain = False
        for item in xrange(len(mytuple)):
            if mytuple[item] > mytuple[item + 1]:
                SwapAgain = True
                temp = mytuple[item]
                mytuple[item] = mytuple[item + 1]
                mytuple[item + 1] = temp
                
    return mytuple
```

I'm trying to assign the value of one item in the tuple to another, but when I try the code above I get this error:

> mytuple[item] = mytuple[item + 1]
>
> TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

I would have preferred to use a list, but my teacher only provided us with a specific tuple. I really appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

Comment: You can't assign a new item to a position in an existing tuple, period. By definition they're immutable, there's no workaround for that. What you can do is create a new tuple with the values or use a list

Comment: Since tuples are immutable, your own option is going to be creating a new one with the items in the order you want. Since that's likely going to happen multiple times during the sort process, converting the tuple to a list once at the very beginning and then converting the final result back to a tuple afterwards would be more efficient than doing it every time a pair of them are swapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tuple is an immutable data type. Once you create it, you can't alter it. So doing this with a list would make sense, and you have the option to return a tuple when the sorting is done, for example:

```
SwapAgain = True
myList = list(myTuple)

while SwapAgain == True:
    SwapAgain = False
    for i in xrange(len(myList)):
        if myList[i] > myList[i + 1]:
            SwapAgain = True
            temp = myList[i]
            myList[i] = myList[i + 1]
            myList[i + 1] = temp

return myList # or return tuple(myList) if you want
```

Answer (score 0):

tuple is fixed structure in python, as the complier told you 'tuple' object does not support item assignment. you should copy it to a new list

Answer (score 0):

Tuple's are immutable so you can set new values or remove items, But if your teacher has specifically asked for tuple then you can create an another tuple called sorted or something where you add these new items and finally replace the original tuple with this one.

Answer (score 0):

As the condition with you is that you have to use a tuple according to your teacher, what would be the best possible solution is that, change the tuple to a list

```
temp_list = list(myTuple)
```

perform the bubble sort on the list and then again change the sorted list to a tuple

```
final_tuple = tuple(temp_list)
```

So, finally you are going to get a sorted tuple.